# Picking and Instancing a Class using a parameter String with Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, oop

It's my first time using TypeScript and using OOP.
I've created an interface for a common brokers methods. (Buy, Sell, sell limit, buy limit)

Then i implemented this interface with my brokers API.
GBM, Bitso, IB, AmeriTrade and so on i want to instance the correct class through a received string in my end point

example: "/api/broker/:brokername"
so i created the following code:

```
class BrokerIgniter {
    
    private instance: any;

    constructor(broker: string) {

        const brokerClass: any = this.pick(broker);
        if(brokerClass) {
            this.run(brokerClass);
        }
    }

    run(ctor: new () => IExecution | IGBMExecution) {
        this.instance = new ctor();
    }

    pick(className: string) {
        const magicWand: { [K: string]: any } = {
            GBM: GBMBroker,
         };
         if (magicWand[className]) {
            return magicWand[className];
        }
        return null;
    }

    get execute() {
        return this.instance;
    }

}
```

the "magicWand variable in the pick method contains a list of classes that implements my common interface (in this case there's only one, at the moment..) in my express post method:

```
const BrokerName = req.params.broker;
if(BrokerName) {
    const Broker = new BrokerIgniter(BrokerName);
    const hash = Broker.execute.createOrderHash('SPXL *', 100, 1);

    super.sendSuccess(res, hash, 'fine');
}
```

My question is:

Is this a good way to make what i want?
there's a name or a pattern for this?
can be improved?

If there's a name for this or a pattern can you name it so that i can learn more about it? i've been checking javascript patterns but nothing found related to this.

cheers.

Comment: Do you have a specific question about that code? Does it cause you any problems? Are just looking to eliminate the `any` type in your code?

Comment: I don't see another way to remove the any.
and problems? well i don't know if i'm doing it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to be able to pass in `string` as the broker key, since this is coming from an API input.

That means you can declare a list of supported classes and their keys outside the `BrokerIgniter` class, (though a static field would work, too).

```
// Sort of guessing at your types here since your example is incomplete.
const brokers: Record<
  string,
  typeof IExecution | typeof IGBMExecution | undefined
> = {
  GBM: GBMBroker
}
```

`brokers` here is typed to to take any string as an index, and return an `IExecution` constructor, an `IGBMExecution` constructor, or `undefined` if they key has no value.

And now `BrokerIgniter` can become simply this:

```
class BrokerIgniter {
    private instance: IExecution | IGBMExecution | undefined;

    constructor(broker: string) {
        const brokerClass = this.pick(broker);
        if(brokerClass) {
            this.run(brokerClass);
        }
    }

    run(ctor: new () => IExecution | IGBMExecution) {
        this.instance = new ctor();
    }

    pick(className: string) {
        return brokers[className] ?? null
    }

    get execute() {
        return this.instance;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSCiAPApsArgFwJYHsB20A3gFDRxKqa4EC80GATmssQL7HGiQywDiAQgFkK6bPiKk4A4SlHVodRszYcuUaNP4McAa2QNoyRBmR4AJjxFVxJMpu16Dipi3ad8EDNABGD-RAAuaAAlVBwGMwAeSU8GLDwAcwAaSQwATwAHZBwAM3JZawIAH3pM7Ly+ISsxYug0c2Qc+OQzYgA+BQk7ISD7XX0VTnB1LX6GWAS8LBMDWzJoDLiANzATaHjPMDxgZCCEAproEsqZSkOS+rNG5rMAbg556GAPJWAMcIAKXzGg2PiEgCUXUe82eeE8Pj8DAAwsMYIoABZYCAAOgyWGAOi+UIB9xB8ywOWxY1h3CBc3xjwwSNRTDwxMcpKguMk+PYjzcjzpHze4SCeGQAHdoB8gTQOvszvJjtJqtRyayQdTkSiNhgtjtOgLhbyGKK8fNOfN0ZieXCAHJgAC2u2gf0SCsp0AYyAwaAYBG+jggAG01BBLTaALrQAD8oegeDQIBAiqNZASrsMB2QouB+Jdbo99BpqvB6u2yANZHYbjBEJMngAglqhdBRo4JlMZh8AOTSVsAlFGM7IIA)

---

That said, this seems like overkill. This is basically the same code.

```
function igniteBroker(brokerKey: string) {
  const brokerClass = brokers[brokerKey]
  return brokerClass ? new brokerClass() : null
}
```

And it's a lot simpler. Maybe you intend to expand on the `BrokerIgniter` class a great deal. But if not, then a simple functional approach will serve you far better.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=20&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECSCiAPApsArgFwJYHsB20A3gFDRxKqa4EC80GATmssQL7HGiQywDiAQgFkK6bPiKk4A4SlHVodRszYcuUaNP4McAa2QNoyRBmR4AJjxFVxJMpu16Dipi3ad8EDNABGD-RAAuaAAlVBwGMwAeSU8GLDwAcwAaSQwATwAHZBwAM3JZawIAH3pM7Ly+ISsxYug0c2Qc+OQzYgA+BQk7ISD7XX0VYhz64BroLAS8LBMtfoYACl85gGlkNKDY+ISASi7oYA8vJccAYXB1OmP-AG0rhlW0gF1JBmQMNAYCO7PuaAB+aB4ZAAdx8fgYPyg812QTwaBAIEGBzwnnoyE8AEFOhMpjNwfMAOTSAnbIA)

Comment: Hey Alex, thank you so much! didn't know about Record Type. Very helpful. Decided to keep the "Igniter" class cause i have other changes in mind Thanks!